# Why is sqlfiddle saying this sql isn't working?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, syntax, sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5cb3a/1

**I work with android sqlite, so I am using non-formatted sql in the form of db.execsql();**

I have narrowed the problem down to the line:

```
INSERT INTO pains (painlocation VARCHAR , painlevel INT(1) , starttime VARCHAR , endtime VARCHAR , symptoms VARCHAR , triggers VARCHAR , medications VARCHAR , othertreatments VARCHAR , notes VARCHAR) VALUES (Eyes , 8 , 12:00 , 12:01 , None , Eyes, None, None , None);
```

Please help me. Everytime it just says this in the android console, and no matter how much error checking and preventing code I put in, I always get the error.:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VARCHAR": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO pains (painlocation VARCHAR , painlevel INT(1) , starttime VARCHAR , endtime VARCHAR , symptoms VARCHAR , triggers VARCHAR , medications VARCHAR , othertreatments VARCHAR , notes VARCHAR) VALUES (Eyes , 8 , 12:00 , 12:01 , None , Eyes, None, None , None);
```

Comment: You don't specify column types in an `INSERT`.

Comment: I am sorry I am really bad at SQL. I guess I was using an outdated tutorial. Is there a good sqlite/android tutorial that you know of?

Comment: Ok I fixed my sql thank you

Comment: No problem. I don't know of any tutorials. Sorry.